# order of the facebook page graph comments with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, angularjs-filter

I put comments of a facebook post in a angularjs loop in http://plnkr.co/edit/bMykiulfzN8tscqfySFA?p=preview

data is from https://graph.facebook.com/618857251494402_804740479572744?access_token=343397335795533|zjYg_5xoTUepxDrTXLYYQR6VDrc

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>comment</th>
      <th>date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="resource in employees | limitTo:2 | orderBy:'created_time':true">
      <td>{{ resource.message }}</td>
      <td>{{ resource.created_time }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Problem is the order : i want the two last comments in the time, but when i put limitTo:2, it's show the two firsts comments ... So, how to get the two lasts comments with limitTo ?

Comment: Did you try placing `| limitTo:2` after orderBy ?

Comment: You're right, it's works :)

Comment: I guessed so, no need to reinvent the wheel by adding another filter when you already have something well tested and which works.. :) So i added an answer for the sake of future readers as well. :)

Comment: Yep, will remove my answer, since it is not really an answer. Bah you need to unaccept it first...

Comment: ok :) sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular filters work as a chain when they are combined, meaning subsequent filter will get the result of previous filter(in the same expression) to work with the data set. In your case you are limiting the initial set of data to 2 records and then ordering the 2 records by `creationDate`. So you should just place the `limitTo:2` after `orderBy` filter.

Try:-

```
<tr ng-repeat="resource in employees | orderBy:'created_time':true | limitTo:2">
```

You do not need to add another filter or reinvent the wheel when we already have one provided along with the angular which is well tested and more efficient (possibly).

Also as a side note, if you are always displaying a static number of latest items (i.e the items or the limit does not change dynamically without the interaction of some trigger), better move the filter to the controller logic (initialization or on a specific action method like a click event etc) and bind with the filtered data. DOM Filters (or filters on the view) are expensive and they add upon to the digest cycle.

**Demo**

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
   $scope.employees = getData().comments.data;


function getData() {
  return {
   "id": "618857251494402_804740479572744",
   "from": {
      "category": "Community",
      "name": "Sexe, Clashs, Batman, Becs Bunsen & Soucoupes Volantes : LE MONDE DU RAT",
      "id": "618857251494402"
   },
   "message": "POST",
   "privacy": {
      "value": ""
   },
   "type": "status",
   "status_type": "mobile_status_update",
   "created_time": "2014-12-18T00:17:36+0000",
   "updated_time": "2014-12-18T19:23:14+0000",
   "is_hidden": true,
   "comments": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": "804740479572744_804740636239395",
            "from": {
               "category": "Community",
               "name": "Sexe, Clashs, Batman, Becs Bunsen & Soucoupes Volantes : LE MONDE DU RAT",
               "id": "618857251494402"
            },
            "message": "test1 (first in the time)",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2014-12-18T00:18:25+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "804740479572744_804779462902179",
            "from": {
               "category": "Reference website",
               "name": "Adopte Un Rat - adopteunrat.com",
               "id": "809567735752704"
            },
            "message": "test",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2014-12-18T01:27:27+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "804740479572744_804967526216706",
            "from": {
               "category": "Community",
               "name": "Sexe, Clashs, Batman, Becs Bunsen & Soucoupes Volantes : LE MONDE DU RAT",
               "id": "618857251494402"
            },
            "message": "test3",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2014-12-18T13:31:22+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "804740479572744_805082169538575",
            "from": {
               "category": "Community",
               "name": "Sexe, Clashs, Batman, Becs Bunsen & Soucoupes Volantes : LE MONDE DU RAT",
               "id": "618857251494402"
            },
            "message": "test4 (last in the time)",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2014-12-18T19:23:14+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         }
      ],
      "paging": {
         "cursors": {
            "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZFhKemIzSTZPREExTURneU1UWTVOVE00TlRjMU9qRTBNVGc1TXpBMU9UUTZMVEU9",
            "before": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZFhKemIzSTZPREEwTnpRd05qTTJNak01TXprMU9qRTBNVGc0TmpFNU1EWTZMVEU9"
         }
      }
   }
}
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>comment</th>
      <th>date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="resource in employees    | orderBy:'created_time':true | limitTo:2">
      <td>{{ resource.message }}</td>
      <td>{{ resource.created_time }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```